# Escape HTML special chars inside Script#dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React application I created custom script tag and added content to it using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` method.

```
                <script
                    type="application/ld+json"
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: `[
                            {
                              "@context": "http://schema.org/",
                              "name": "${data.profile.name}",
                            }

                        ]`,
                    }}
                />
```

Problem is that `data.profile.name` contains quotes (`"`), so I want to escape `${data.profile.name}` string, so all special characters will be replaced with their HTML counterparts  (so quote `"` should become `"&quot;`).

Is there any way to do it with standard JavaScript or React utilities? I don't want to create custom utility function with regexps like below:

`myStr.replace(/"/g, "&quot;")`

Thanks

Comment: you can use 'react-html-parser' [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-html